# Modeling something with a lot of holes

Tags: modifiers, topology

[image: Base of coffee machine]
Can anyone give me some tips on how to model this plane? I've tried everything from booleans to modeling by hand but I always end up with a weird looking mesh that doesn't have a good topolgy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Boolean* should work:

[image]

You can also create this mesh and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> in order to fill, then <kbd>X</kbd> > *Limited Dissolve* if you want to remove most ofthe inner edges (as for Boolean, you'll always need edges that connect inner edges to outer edges):

[image]

Or for a cleaner topology, create a plane, subdivide once, delete the inner vertex, extrude inwards and *LoopTools > Circle* to get this:

[image]

Duplicate it, join the original with the duplication with a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops* and enable the *Merge* option in the Operator Box:

[image]

Duplicate the 2 holes, repeat the operation, use more vertices for the big holes:

[image]